# Symfony2 POST value from Twig to controller action

Tags: php, symfony

I'm new in Symfony2.I want to post a value from twig to controller. I know how to pass values through url. But i want How to post a data from twig to a controller action without passing that values to url?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? There's likely something you can do to get around needing this capability... If you give an example of your goal, perhaps we could help outline a suitable alternative. The reason I say this is that I actually asked a similar question here once, only to discover I was approaching the problem from the wrong angle.

Comment: hai..thanks for your quick response . Actually I have a situation that , I need to delete a particular row from a list of rows from a table,for this I'm passing an id to the particulal controller function. I did it through url and i can delete it. but I face a problem that if a user directly enter a url with id ,it delete.

Comment: Know that a user could also pass fake POST data to the controller and delete it anyway. You should just use authentication in your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a limitation of symfony, but the http protocol: you can pass values using either GET or POST parameters. GET valuas are passed by simple urls, for post you need to use forms or javascript.

It is only a symfony2 related question if you want to embedd another controller in your view - for this, [see the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers)